# How to install Laravel 4?

Tags: php, git, laravel, composer-php

How to install Laravel 4? I have downloaded the latest Laravel zip file and also installed Composer on my Windows 7 PC. I have tried to seek a tutorial on this.

Do I really need to have Git installed in order to use Laravel? Can I use composer to install Laravel from my local downloaded zip file? Or, can I just extract the zip file and put into my local web root folder to start working with Laravel? How about installing a third party component? All have to be installed from the internet? Can it be installed from local source with Composer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose if you run `composer install --prefer-dist` you won't need git. But then it's not a very wise decision to develop without version control, specially a distributed version control that can be used offline. So, I think you better install Git, use composer to automatically download and install all the dependencies.

I think it would be possible to download all the dependencies and dependencies of dependencies one by one from their repositories and copy them in a specific directory in your installation and then make them to autoload using psr-0. But I don't think you would enjoy that much pain. Composer can do a much better job handling all that for you. It would be faster too. The zip file you downloaded only brings you a config file for composer and a directory skeleton, not even the framework itself. The real downloading is done by Composer.

Although, after Composer downloaded everything you can make a copy of the installed structure to use it for your later projects, but then your installation would be a bit stale I think.

Also Composer makes a local cache of the packages it downloads.

*Excerpt from [5 features to know about Composer PHP](http://moquet.net/blog/5-features-about-composer-php/):*

> Since November 2012, Composer automatically stores the archive when you download a dist package. By default, dist packages are used for tagged versions, for instance "symfony/symfony": "v2.1.4", or even a wildcard or range version like "2.1.*" or ">=2.2,<2.3-dev" if you use stable as your minimum-stability.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Is that mean everytime when I start new Laravel project, I have to use composer to install everything? If I build my CMS on Laravel, how can I reuse my CMS on other projects? Do I really need to upload it to server?

Comment: Basically yes, it's better to use composer each time. 

If you use a form of version control you can keep your repository (I prefer a remote repository), develop, update the repository and deploy by pulling from repository, then you can run `composer install` to install all the dependencies including Laravel.

This way if you need to use your app in another project, you just need to fork it! Or if it's a general purpose component like a simple CMS you can consider building a [package](http://laravel.com/docs/packages "Lavarvel Documentation - Package Development") out of it.